# Convert Mathematica equations into R code

Tags: r, latex, wolfram-mathematica, mathml

Is there an easy way to convert Mathematica equations into R code?   I have several equations that consist of dozens of terms with subscripts, superscripts, and greek letters.  For example, here's a small part of one equation in Latex format:

```
m_2_2= 48 b_1 c_2^2 d_1 \rho ^4+48 b_2 c_1^2 d_2 \rho ^4+216 b_2 c_1 c_2 d_1 \rho ^3+216 b_1 c_1 c_2 d_2 \rho ^3+96 b_1 c_2^2 d_1 \rho ^2+96 b_2 c_1^2 d_2 \rho ^2 + ...
```

I can copy from Mathematica as plain text, input text, Latex, or MathML, but how can I get any of those formats to work in R with all of the subscripts, superscripts, and greek?  Unfortunately, the equations are so long that retyping manually would likely result in errors.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you have can have underscores in variable names so those shouldn't cause any issues.  You might need to use gsub or an equivalent to replace the greek letters/latex with valid variable names though - most likely by getting rid of the leading backslash

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example? That is, could you provide a simple, (at least somewhat) representative piece of Mathematica code? My instinct is Mathematica --> plain text --> R --> `gsub()` --> `eval(parse(text=...))`.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I'm not sure how to copy and paste the Mathematica code into this question in a format that's easier to read than Latex.  I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is builtin support for exporting expressions to Fortran and C.
I suggest you export the expression to C and then edit the C expression.

Details here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneratingCAndFortranExpressions.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that tutorial.  If I convert to C, can I then convert the Power(a,b) function to an exponent in R?  How do I Subscript(c,d) into something more manageable?

Comment: Define one!  Power <- function(a,b) {a^b}

Comment: Thanks.  I think I have it working now using CForm[], a Power function, and Find+Replace for the subcript issues.