# Converting C code into R code: parsing to change a C function in R (pow(a,b) to a^b)

Tags: c, r, wolfram-mathematica

I am using Mathematica to generate equations as C code (using CForm[]), in order to export the equation as a character string and use it in R.

For example, the CForm[] output imported into R as a character string looks like this:

```
"Tau * Power(Omega * (-(R * Gamma) + R),(Tau + R))"
```

My question is how best to convert the above C code into an R expression like this:

```
Tau * (Omega * (-(R * Gamma) + R ))^(Tau + R)
```

Following a suggestion from an earlier post about converting Mathematica code into R code [(Convert Mathematica equations into R code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952792/convert-mathematica-equations-into-r-code), I'm aware that a reasonable thing to do is to redefine Power() as a function, i.e.,:

```
Power <- function(a,b) {a^b}
```

But, through a series of tests, I discovered that evaluating an expression that's in the form of:

```
eval(parse(text="Tau * (Omega * (-(R * Gamma) + R ))^(Tau + R)"))
```

is much faster (about 4 times fast on my mac) than the alternative of defining Power() as a function and evaluating the following:

```
eval(parse(text="Tau * Power(Omega * (-(R * Gamma) + R),(Tau + R))"))
```

It seems like a complex pattern matching problem, but I could not find any solutions. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: That's not standard C code, not even an expression.

Comment: The first code I provide is one part of CForm[] output from Mathematica, imported into R as a character string. The rest is all R code. Thank you.

Comment: @Olaf is right. This is not standard C code. Do not trust `CForm[]` blindly to convert Mathematica expressions to C ...  Have a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46844/real-and-or-improved-cform-of-expressions)

Comment: Thank you for your pointer. My question is to do with manipulating a character string in R. I wanted to provide a context by mentioning how the string was created, but the use of CForm[] is not central to my issue. Thank you.

Comment: That's a really broad question. It's like asking how to make a C interpreter in R. Research how to build a simple lexer and parser to build a simple C arithmetic calculator. In particular, you can learn a lot about those two by searching how to build a calculator with order of operators via recursive descent parsing. You can build from the idea to build your own eval function.

Comment: That's not a job for regexpr (although it might work), but a full-grown expression parser plus composer. You might be better of either using a true C function and call it from R or convert it manually, depending on how often you do this. (best would be to find an R-code generator for Mathematica, of course!

Comment: Thank you for the pointers about parsing / recursive descent parsing. As the literature on parsing seems rather dense, an example would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @TK2013 [RDP-Calculator](https://gist.github.com/ascv/5022712) This is a very simple-one-page calculator written in python. It achieves order of operations from recursive descent parsing. The idea is to extend this parsing technique to accept tokens that aren't just numbers but variables that represent C variables in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

1. Your equation is *not* standard C code. `CForm[]` from Mathematica is not translating your code to proper C syntax. Perhaps you could follow [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46844/real-and-or-improved-cform-of-expressions) and use `SymbolicC` to solve this part
2. Your question is more about parsing  from Language A to Language B. As mentioned by @Olaf in the comments: *You might be better of either using a true C function and call it from R or convert it manually, depending on how often you do this*

But, as per your request (if I understood correctly what you want to achieve) and for educational purposes; here's an example in which we will use R to convert your "pseudo-C" string and create an in-lined `cfunction()`

**Note**: This is by no mean intended to be elegant or practical, but the general idea should hopefully help you getting started

---

Assuming the following equation:

```
v1 <- "4 * Power(Omega * (-(R * Gamma) + R),(Tau + R))"
```

Extract all variables and functions from the original string

```
n1 <- stringi::stri_extract_all_words(v1)[[1]]
```

Create a named vector of "functions to recode" (and a subset without them and without numerics)

```
newFunc <- c("Power" = "pow")   
n2 <- setdiff(n1, names(newFunc))
n3 <- n2[is.na(as.numeric(n2))]
```

Build a replacement list to feed `gsubfn()`. For the sake of this example, we replace the old function with the new one and wrap `asReal()` around the variables

```
toreplace <- setNames(
  as.list(c(newFunc, paste0("asReal(", n3, ")"))), 
  c(names(newFunc), n3)
)

v2 <- gsubfn::gsubfn(paste(names(toreplace), collapse = "|"), toreplace, v1)
```

---

You could then pass this new string to a `cfunction()` to execute in R

```
#install.packages("inline")
library(inline)
foo <- cfunction(
  sig  = setNames(rep("integer", length(n3)), n3), 
  body = paste0(
    "SEXP result = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, 1));
     REAL(result)[0] = ", v2, "; 
     UNPROTECT(1);
     return result;"
  )
)
```

This should be faster than using `eval(parse("..."))` with `^` or defining a `Power()` function

```
Tau = 21; Omega = 22; R = 42; Gamma = 34
Power <- function(x,y) {x^y}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  C  = foo(Omega, R, Gamma, Tau),
  R1 = eval(parse(text="4 * ((Omega * (-(R * Gamma) + R ))^(Tau + R))")),
  R2 = eval(parse(text="4 * Power(Omega * (-(R * Gamma) + R),(Tau + R))")), 
  times = 10L
)

#Unit: microseconds
# expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
#    C   1.233   2.194   5.9555   2.9955   3.302   34.194    10
#   R1 190.012 202.781 230.5187 218.1035 243.891  337.209    10
#   R2 189.162 191.798 374.5778 207.6875 225.078 1868.746    10
```

Comment: Thank you Steven for a neat answer! A follow up question: I realised that the the foo function fails to be constructed if there is a numerical element in the character vector. E.g., `v1<- "4 * Power(Omega * (-(R * Gamma) + R),(Tau + R))"`. Could you point out why this might be an issue? Thank you.

Comment: @TK2013 The issue arises in `sig = ...` in the `foo()` function. You are creating a named vector `n2` with "4" = "integer" (which is not right). I edited the post to account for that.